# Spring Batch startup failures

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a very frustrating problem, a spring batch application that was working fine before christmas has stopped working.  There have been a few changes but Ive tried reverting all of them, nothing works.

I have a step:

```
    <batch:step id="customerCampaignFileWritingStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk writer="customerCampaignFileWriter"
                         commit-interval="1000"
                         reader="tokenisedDatabaseReader" />
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="springBatchStepTimerListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="customerCampaignFileCleanupListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="*" to="customerCampaignLoadToProductionTransferStep"/>
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="loadingRepositoryClearDownStep"/>
    </batch:step>
```

Reader is define in JavaConfig:

Reader:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<CustomerCampaignLoad> tokenisedDatabaseReader (
        @Value("#{jobParameters['customerCampaign_input_file']}") String inputFileName
) {
    HibernatePagingItemReader<CustomerCampaignLoad> reader = new HibernatePagingItemReader();
    reader.setQueryString("from CustomerCampaignLoad where fileName = :filename");
    reader.setPageSize(1000);
    reader.setUseStatelessSession(true);
    SessionFactory fact = this.entityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    reader.setSessionFactory(fact);
    //p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"

    Map<String, Object> paramVals = new HashMap<>();
    paramVals.put("filename", inputFileName);
    reader.setParameterValues(paramVals);

    return reader;
}
```

Writer:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<CustomerCampaignLoad> customerCampaignFileWriter(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['customerCampaign_results_file']}") String fullyQualifiedResourceName,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['generic_step_scope_results_file_field_delimiter']}") String outputFileDelimiter,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['customerCampaign_field_names']}") String outputFileHeaderFields,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['customerCampaign_field_token_name']}") String entityTokenFieldName) {

    final FlatFileItemWriter<CustomerCampaignLoad> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    final DelimitedLineAggregator<CustomerCampaignLoad> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();

    delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(outputFileDelimiter);

    // Here's where you customise the output file fields.
    delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(customerCampaign -> new String[] {
            customerCampaign.getCustomerNumber(),
            customerCampaign.getCampaignId(),
            customerCampaign.getCampaignExpiry().toString(),
            customerCampaign.getCampaignName(),
            customerCampaign.getCampaignBatch(),
            customerCampaign.getCrn(),
            customerCampaign.getStoreEposNumber(),
            customerCampaign.getToken()
    });

    flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);
    flatFileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fullyQualifiedResourceName));
    final FlatFileHeaderCallback flatFileHeaderCallBack
            = writer -> writer.write(outputFileHeaderFields+","+entityTokenFieldName);
    flatFileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(flatFileHeaderCallBack);
    flatFileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    flatFileItemWriter.setAppendAllowed(false);

    return flatFileItemWriter;
}
```

The startup error is:

```
2021-01-17 10:26:44,038 ERROR [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerCampaignfileWritingStep': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233 implementing org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter' for property 'itemWriter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233 implementing org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter' for property 'itemWriter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.specsavers.digital.data.ingest.launch.Application.main(Application.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

It looks like the writer being injected isn't an interface as those listed in the exception do not include the desired type.  But it IS declared an interface.

The only think it COULD be possibly is the mix of XML and JavaConfig.  but it was working fine.

Comment: I can't be sure about the root cause of this issue without being able to reproduce it, but I recommend returning the most specific reader/writer type so that Spring Batch can proxy batch artifacts correctly. In your case, have you tried to make the return type of the `customerCampaignFileWriter` method as `FlatFileItemWriter<CustomerCampaignLoad>` instead of `ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<CustomerCampaignLoad>`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've tried that, in fact thats how it started when it was working.

Comment: Do you mean it's sill not working? If this is the case, please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work wither way